# Using numbers in a name

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"Name12,345" vs "Name12345"
How would you properly write this kind of notation? (If there is any proper way to write it)
I naturally want to include the comma to separate the groups of digits, but I'm not sure if it's the right syntax when used in a name like this. 
Perhaps it's better to use "Name-12,345" or something similar?

Comment: So is the person's first name "345" and last name "Name12"?  If you are naming something like a column in a table then this is not a question about English, but rather about practices in the specialty you're writing about.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about variable naming are off-topic.

Comment: No. Put the question into this context. When a person is created, they share the name of their progenitor incremented by one. Name12,345 is the 12,345th offspring of Name.

Comment: @HotLicks I am not sure what variable naming is. If the question isn't clear enough, I will revise it.

Comment: So it's a question about whatever mythical culture you're discussing.  You can make your own rules.

Comment: @HotLicks Is it mythological? Are there no instances of this in English whatsoever? Some pronoun with a number attached to it?

Comment: Outside of Oriental cultures, likely the highest numbered names of successors are the Catholic popes, of which St John XXIII likely has the greatest ordinal value.  And virtually all Western kings have followed the same pattern of using Roman numerals (and rarely going beyond 10).

Comment: @HotLicks I'm curious - which Oriental cultures use numbered names?

Comment: @Lawrence - I don't know that any do, but then I don't know much about Oriental cultures.

Comment: @B.fox Please specify the culture / locality you're referring to. I'm surprised at the large numbers in the names, but the conventions you're after are likely to be specific to the culture / locality.

Comment: @HotLicks Apologies for my confusion.

Comment: I think the problem right now with this question is that we have no idea what you're talking about. A real example would probably help.

Comment: No no no, I was just using an example of what I meant. I am not referring to any cultures or anything like that. I just want to know the right way to write such a thing in general. It's not a mythological world building thing and it's not related to something specific.

Comment: @B.fox - It's mythological if it's never going to happen in the real world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at some common examples in English:

*King Louis XI*

*Pope John Paul II*

*The year 2000*

*70 B.C*.

*Super Bowl XX*

What you definitely don't see is a comma. Also, you see a space between the numeral and the word(s) around it. With big numbers, I would stay with arabic numerals (2000), but with smaller numbers, I would use roman numerals (XXII).

Thus, **Name 12345**

However, if we're talking parts to a complex machinery, or some such, where letters and numbers are part of the entity, I would go with

*Part 47a23b*

*Flu virus H7N7*    and the like

Comment: I think this adequately covers the use of numbers in a pronoun, and answers the question. Thank you!